# ffmpeg add video to the start and end of another

Tags: linux, find, ffmpeg

So I am using the following to convert all our videos in `/home/vids` to mp4 and output them in `/home/vids2` but now I would like to add another video that plays before and after each video in `/home/vids`.

The video link is `/home/intro/play.mp4` this video should be played before and after each of the videos in `/home/vids`. To clarify if `/home/intro/play.mp4` is 10 seconds long and if a video in `/home/vids' is 30 seconds long then the finished video should be 50 seconds long after you combine them.

```
find /home/vids -type f -execdir ffmpeg -i '{}' -filter:v drawtext="fontfile=/root/FreeSans.ttf:text='TEXT EXAMPLE':fontcolor=black@1.0:fontsize=24:y=h-line_h-30:x=w/20*mod(t\,60)" -f mp4 -vcodec libx264 -preset fast -profile:v main -acodec aac -movflags +faststart '/home/vids2/{}.mp4' \;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the videos are encoded using the same codecs you can utilize the `concat` operator.

> If you have media files with exactly the same codec and codec parameters you can concatenate them as described in "Concatenation of files with same codecs". If you have media with different codecs you can concatenate them as described in "Concatenation of files with different codecs" below.

```
$ cat build_ffmpegs.bash
#!/bin/bash

intro=/home/intro/play.mp4
outro=/home/intro/play.mp4

cd /home/vid

for i in vid*; do
    ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 \
      -i < <(printf "file '%s'\n" $intro $(readlink -f $i) $outro) \
      -c copy /home/vid2/output_${i}
done
```

Running this will generate `ffmpeg` commands like so:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i < <(printf "file '%s'\n" /home/intro/play.mp4 /home/vid/vid1.mp4 /home/intro/play.mp4) -c copy /home/vid2/output_vid1.mp4
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i < <(printf "file '%s'\n" /home/intro/play.mp4 /home/vid/vid2.mp4 /home/intro/play.mp4) -c copy /home/vid2/output_vid2.mp4
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i < <(printf "file '%s'\n" /home/intro/play.mp4 /home/vid/vid3.mp4 /home/intro/play.mp4) -c copy /home/vid2/output_vid3.mp4
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i < <(printf "file '%s'\n" /home/intro/play.mp4 /home/vid/vid4.mp4 /home/intro/play.mp4) -c copy /home/vid2/output_vid4.mp4
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i < <(printf "file '%s'\n" /home/intro/play.mp4 /home/vid/vid5.mp4 /home/intro/play.mp4) -c copy /home/vid2/output_vid5.mp4
```

You should be able to adapt the `ffmpeg` commands to whatever other specifics you need from here.

#### References

- https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate